# Multiple datasources for same SQL DB

Tags: google-app-maker

I have an app page that shows information from the same table in 2 places on a page.

In the place A, I want an editable field that is owned by the current user.

In the place B, I want to see the list of entries for all users.

I thought I could somehow have two pointers into the same table by configuring more than one datasource for the table, and bind placeA/B widgets to the two separate datasource.

However, I could not find out how I can bind a panel or widget to a specific datasource within a table.

What bugs me is that clearly the UI allows me to add multiple datasources for a table, so I probably misunderstand what the usercase for multiple datasources are.

My current plan is to ivestigate whether I can create a computed datasource that limits results to just the current user, but I don't understand how I could updated a computed datasource (which is something I want to do).

This is probably less than clear, happy to add clarifying information.

Many thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. App maker behaves as I thought it should be. The two datasources are behaving as two cursors into the same table. For some reason, I could not seem to find the 2nd datasource in the widget dropdown for datasource, but I could find it by selecting "Advanced" and then finding datasource starting from "datasources" instead of "widget.datasource".

Nothing to see here, move along now ;)